# Simultaneous zeros of $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}f(n)\cos(g(x,n))$ and $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}f(n)\cos(g(x,n)+\frac{\pi}{2})$

Tags: sequences-and-series, roots, riemann-zeta

> Let $f(n)$ and $g(x,n)$ be real functions. If $$A=\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}f(n)\cos(g(x,n))\, \text{ and } \,B=\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}f(n)\cos\left(g(x,n)+\frac{\pi}{2}\right),$$ under what conditions does it occur that $A=B=0$?

I ask this question because I am looking at the sums $$\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{(\text{-}1)^{n+1}\cos(x\ln(n))}{n^a}\,\text{ and }\,\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{(\text{-}1)^{n+1}\cos(x\ln(n)+\frac{\pi}{2})}{n^a},$$ which are the real and imaginary parts of the Dirichlet eta function with complex argument $a+xi$ (with $0<a\leq\frac{1}{2}$). It seems from anecdotal evidence that these two sums only both equal zero when $a$ is $\frac{1}{2}$ (and $x$ is the imaginary part of any non-trivial zero of the zeta function).

Comment: Is your definition of $A$ and $B$ right? Shouldn't the summands depend on $n$ as well?

Comment: I wasn't really sure whether to call it a function of $x$ or of $n$.

Comment: Well, your summation is over $n$, so the summands must have some dependence on this index (I'm assuming $x$ is not a function of $n$). In your example it seems by direct comparison, that you have $g(x,n)=x ln(x)$ and $f(n)=(-1)^{n+1}/(n^a)$.

Comment: Ah okay, that makes sense.

Comment: Seems you could write $B$ as $-\sum_n\, f(n)\sin(g(x, n))$, then look for zeros of $C(z) = \sum_n\, f(n)e^{-i g(z, n)}$.